# React/JS not showing possibilities (intellisense) VSCODE on react array.map() parameters

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, intellisense

I have products.js like below:

```
    const products = [
   {
     _id: "1",
      name: "Airpods Wireless Bluetooth Headphones",
     image: "/images/airpods.jpg",
   },
   ];
```

I have Home.js :

```
export default function HomeScreen() {
   return (
    <div>
      <h1>Lasted Production</h1>
      <Row>
       {products.map((product) => (
         <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
          <Product product={product} />
       </Col>
       ))}
     </Row>
  </div>
   );
   }
```

on another file Product.js below, when I put dot after {product},I expect {product._id},{product.name},{product.image} auto popup as intellisense, but it not work

```
export default function Product({ product }) {
return (
    <Card.Body>
      <a href={`/product/${product._id}`}>
        <Card.Title as="div">
          <strong>{product.name}</strong> //.name can only manual input,no intellisense popup 
        </Card.Title>
      </Card.Text>
     </Card.Body>
     );
   }
```

I've been struggling with this for a while and I haven't found a way to do this yet.

Comment: I think you're expecting a lot given the only potential clue you've given JS is some ad-hoc objects that happen to share some property keys. If you want robust, consistent IntelliSense provide typing information so it doesn't have to guess what you really mean.

Comment: intellisense only work on home.js,but never work on Product.js

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of achieving this is by using typescript interfaces. You can find the reference for the same [here](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/defining-props-in-react-function-component-with-typescript).

For JavaScript I've made this workaround for you:

```
import React from "react";
import { Card } from "react-bootstrap";
import Rating from "./Rating"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Product(prod) {
  let product =   {
    _id: '',
    name: '',
    image: '',
    description: '',
    brand: '',
    category: '',
    price: 0,
    countInStock: 0,
    rating: 0,
    numReviews: 0,
  }

  product = {...prod}
  return (
    <Card className="my-3 p-3 rounded">
      <Link to={`/products/${product._id}`}> 
        <Card.Img src={product.image} variant="top" />
      </Link>
      <Card.Body>
        <Link to={`/products/${product._id}`}>
          <Card.Title as="div">
            <strong>{product.name}</strong>
          </Card.Title>
        </Link>
        <Card.Text as="div">
          <div className="my-3">
            {/* {product.rating} from {product.numReviews} */}
            <Rating value={product.rating} text={`${product.numReviews}reviews`}/>
          </div>
        </Card.Text>
        <Card.Text as="h3">
          ${product.price}
        </Card.Text>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

**(I've swapped your old *product* prop with *prod* and local variable name is *product* to save time)**

What I've done here is I've created a local variable

```
  let product =   {
    _id: '',
    name: '',
    image: '',
    description: '',
    brand: '',
    category: '',
    price: 0,
    countInStock: 0,
    rating: 0,
    numReviews: 0,
  }
```

> For better practice you can declare this variable in you product.js file and import it here in case there are multiple file where it'll be used.

After this I'm replacing the content of the local variable with prop object.

```
  product = {...prod}
```

Now you can use this variable in your code and get the suggestions.

I've attached the screenshot below where we've suggestions as expected:

[image]

Comment: I  add `export default products`,and import products variable to Home.JS, but still without intellisense, when i put dot after {product.} on Product JS, no {product.name} pop up.

Comment: Nilesh Pal, I just send your a mail of my code , I'm in Win10, Vscode ivsersion is 1.82.0

Comment: hunpo, now it is working checkout the updated answer. let me know in case if you need further help